# Example of continuous transient Markov chain in detailed balance?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have been thinking of such a chain but I've found none. I thought about random walk on $\mathbb{N}$ with probability p to go to right and $q=1-p$ to go back(i.e. this is the transition probabilities for the jump chain) with $p>q$. I have not been able to show that this chain is in detailed balance. Can anyone give me an example of such chain (which according to my book does exist)?

Comment: From what [little](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance#Reversible_Markov_chains) I know about the detailed balance, can't you just take a standard random walk on $\Bbb Z^3$? If you need it to be a continuous-time Markov Chain, let transition occur always with $\mathcal E(1)$ arrivals.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about it. How would you define the vector $\mathbf{v}$ s.t. $v_i *q_{ij}=v_j*q_{ji}$ where $q_{ij}$ are the entries in the Q-matrix and $\mathbf{v}$ is a probability distribution?

Comment: Does it necessary have to be a bounded measure?

Comment: Well it is given that this Markov chain has a Q-matrix so I was not considering random walks in higher dimensions.

Comment: *this Markov chain has a Q-matrix so I was not considering random walks in higher dimensions*... Sorry but how the existence of a Q-matrix would eliminate *random walks in higher dimensions*?

Comment: Got something from my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments you are asking for an example of a transient Markov chain with a reversible distribution. In particular, this distribution ought to be stationary and the Markov chain should be positive recurrent,  hence it could not be transient.

Comment: *which according to my book does exist*... Which book?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I might be mistaken in some of the assumptions. The exact question is the following:
Show that there is a transient Markov chain $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ and a probability distribution v s.t. v and Q (the Q-matrix for the Markov chain) are in detailed balance.

Comment: This clearly assumes that such chain exists.

Comment: And i forgot the important assumption that the Markov chain is irreducible.

Comment: [A basic result of the field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) is that *an irreducible chain has a stationary distribution if and only if all of its states are positive recurrent*. // Which book?

Comment: Well it's an old exam question from my teacher which i assumed was from the book(Markov chain Norris or some other book about that field). But this is maybe just wrong unless we just say that the probability distribution is just some distribution say $v=(1,0,0,...)$ (because it is never made clear that this is exactly the probability distributin for the associated Q-matrix) then this holds for my initial proposition.

Comment: I doubt this is in Norris. Note that the v in your last comment is NEVER stationary unless state $1$ is a *sink*, that is, $q_{1j}=0$ for every $j\ne1$.

Comment: Yes I know that. Well what about having the probability measure not bounded, say like Ilya said above, random walk in $\mathbf{Z}^3$ in continuous time and every element happens with frequency $\lambda = 1$?

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: How would I set up the Q-matrix for that process so I can fulfill the equation $v_i*q_{ij}=v_j*q_{ji}$? I guess then $q_{ij}=c*1/6$ where c is a constant when $|i-j|=1$ else it would be zero. Then $v=c*(1,1,...)$ which again can't become probability distribution. Am I right?

Comment: Yes I did notice, and you are right, I was wrong there.